# Sharepoint WFE server not accessible

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

Below is a SharePoint network diagram in which there are 2 Sharepoint WFE servers (3 and 4). Sharepoint 2013 is installed and farm configured on both the servers, first on Server3 then on Server4. When installing on server4 we have joined it to the existing Sharepoint farm which is (Server3). When Server3 is switched off the application is down and central administration is not accessible from Server4. If Server4 is switched off and Server3 is switched on Central administration site of Server3 is accessible. However both are using the existing SAN DB.

Is it possible for Server4 to work the same way if Server3 is down?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like you provision the Central admin on one server(Server 3) that's why when you shut it down then Central admin is not working. You have to provision the Central admin on the server 4 as well.

- when you run the Config wizard on the Server 4 to joining the farm, during that click on the Advance option and select use this machine to host Central Admin.
- You can configure the Load Balancer on it after that.

Please check this article for complete details and supported method.

[SharePoint Central Administration: High Availability, Load Balancing, Security & General Recommendations](http://www.harbar.net/articles/spca.aspx)